# Loading JSON var into an existing HTML table through Button-Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have an already written (in html) table and i want to "rewrite" it when i press the "refresh data" button. So far, i lose all of my css style for a reason (like i' m creating a new table from scratch). My code:

HTML - Table :

```
<div id="priceInfo">
            <button id="priceInfoB">refresh data</button>
        </div>
        <table id="myTable" border='1'>
            <tr class="head">
                <th></th>
                <th data-city="ny">New York</th>
                <th data-city="il">Chicago</th>
                <th data-city="ca">San Francisco</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class='rowTH' id="one"><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="0">A Poetic Perspective</a></th>
                <td>Sat, 4 Feb 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 3 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 17 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <th class='rowTH' id="two"><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="1">Walt Whitman at War</a></th>
                <td>Sat, 7 Apr 2012<br />11am - 1pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 5 May 2012<br />11am - 1pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 19 May 2012<br />11am - 1pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class='rowTH' id="three"><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="2">Found Poems &amp; Outsider Poetry</a></th>
                <td>Sat, 9 Jun 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 7 Jul 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 21 Jul 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <th class='rowTH' id="four"><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="3">Natural Death: An Exploration</a></th>
                <td>Sat, 4 Aug 2012<br />11am - 4pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 8 Sep 2012<br />11am - 4pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 15 Sep 2012<br />11am - 4pm</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

JSON Var :

```
var eventsJson='{"events":{"event":[{"id":"1","name":"A Poetic Perspective","isFree":"true","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-05-02","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-05-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-06-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Vivamus elementum, diam eget ullamcorper fermentum, ligula libero euismod massa, quis condimentum tellus lacus sit."},{"id":"2","name":"Walt Whitman at War","isFree":"false","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-07-02","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-07-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-08-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Donec convallis eu metus eget dictum. Etiam non lobortis dui."},{"id":"3","name":"Found Poems & Outsider Poetry","isFree":"false","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-06-02","eventTime":"11:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-07-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-06-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Ut fermentum, elit vel iaculis viverra, dui libero ultrices nibh, ut ornare."},{"id":"4","name":"Natural Death: An Exploration","isFree":"true","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-05-02","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-05-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-06-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquet urna ut tortor consequat."}]}}';
```

Any help will be appreaciated. Any manual and/or command i havent thought about will be helpful!

Comment: You need `AJAX`,  Nice tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Comment: i can do this only with ajax? no other way?..Also, ajax needs it's own libraries? Thank you

Comment: Ajax can be done with native JS functions (no library). http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ But since you used the `jQuery` tag on your question, just use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), which is provided by that library.

Comment: `AJAX` can be used with `XmlHttpRequest`. No external library required.

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through the json data
- For each record, clone the table rows you need. Demo here

[Using jQuery to build table rows from Ajax response(Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724017/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-responsejson)

- Swap the cell data with data from your JSON
- Append the rows to the table

Comment: will ajax keep my css?..cause creating the table is easy, but what i must do to keep my formating style?..using the #myTable doesn't seem to help

Comment: yes if you clone the row it will keep the same attributes, including the class

Comment: #myTable is your table id, not the css class