# how display data in a html page after parsing them from an odata server?

Tags: javascript, html

I parsed some data from an odata server.I succeeded to parse it from the server and I want to display the obtained data into a html page:
index.html:

```
<div class="project_info">
```

projects.js:

```
    var serverPath="path_to_odata_server";
$(document).ready(function(){

  serverPath += "?$select=project_name,status,start_date";
  $.getJSON(serverPath,function(result){
    var tr;
    $.each(result,function(i,field){
      for(var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        console.log(field[i].name);
        console.log(field[i].status);
        console.log(field[i].real_start);
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<tr><td class=\"project_title\">" + field[i].name + "</td></tr>");
        tr.append("<tr><td class=\"project_status\">" + field[i].status + "</td></tr>");
        tr.append("<tr><td class=\"project_date\">" + field[i].start_start + "</td></tr>");
        $('.project_info').append(tr);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

when I used `console.log()` I got the data that I wanted to display but I couldn't display it into the html page.Should I use `document.write` to write data into the html page?

Comment: When you're appending the table cells to the row, try removing the `<tr>...</tr>` from the string.

Comment: You can see this demo it's very easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724017/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-responsejson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete `<tr></tr>` and try this program:

```
tr = $('<tr/>');
tr.append("<td class=\"project_title\">" + field[i].name + "</td>");
tr.append("<td class=\"project_status\">" + field[i].status + "</td>");
tr.append("<td class=\"project_date\">" + field[i].start_start + "</td>");
$('.project_info').append(tr);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one.

```
tr = "<tr><td class=\"project_title\">" + field[i].name + "</td></tr>";
tr += "<tr><td class=\"project_status\">" + field[i].status + "</td></tr>";
tr += "<tr><td class=\"project_date\">" + field[i].start_start + "</td></tr>";

$('.project_info').append(tr);
```

Comment: Make sure all cells are in a single `<tr></tr>`, then it should work.