# Datatable from server json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I submitted a form data to a backend Flask application as ajax post request. Backend process uses data to query database then returns json object back to Ajax. How to construct datatable from this json object?

My Ajax post request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/process',
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                //response looks like this: 
                //[{"country": "USA", "code": "1007-01" },{"country": "UK", "code": "1100-04" }]

            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My flask application

```
@app.route('/process', methods=["POST"])
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       country = request.form['id'].encode("utf-8")
       #query database and store result in dict
       result = query_database(country)
       return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: This seems like more of a jQuery question than a Flask question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to build table rows from Ajax response (Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724017/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-response-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your datatable with your ajax call as datasource

```
let datatable = $('#my-table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/process',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            $('#myform').serialize()
        } 
    }
});
```

now you just need to format your response like this

```
{ 
    data:[/*your Data*/]
}
```