# Attempting to display Json result but getting only [Object,Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am fetching one row from database in Object format.

here is my .cs code

```
public JsonResult GetApplicationDetail(string id){
    sp_Application_Result AppObj = new sp_Application_Result();
    ObjectResult obj = db.sp_Application(id);
    foreach (sp_Application_Result i in obj){
        AppObj = i;
    }
    return Json(AppObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and here is my script code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Application/GetApplicationDetail/",
    datatype: "json",
    data:  {"id" : name} ,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
);
```

when I'm trying to show response, it's showing `[Object,object]`

I am not getting how to show response result, actually I want to store response data into table.

Comment: display in console.log

Comment: only `console.log(response)` can expand and print objects, instead `alert` can only print/display strings so either use `console.log` or `JSON.stringify(response)` before `alert`

Comment: Either you can log the response directly using `console.log(response)` or you can transform the json object to string to be able to display it in the alert `alert(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: Try to console your response. 
console.log(response), then see what you are getting there

Comment: hey... Try to `console.log()` your response? xD

Answer (score 4):

Let's try with

JSON.stringify it will convert the object response to string

`alert(JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: Thanks Tai Le,
already tried with this solution, but not able to store that result in Table.

Comment: hmm. which table?

Comment: I have used in view
<table id="datatable">    </table>
so, i want to store json response in this table.
Tai Le can you please help.

Comment: I found some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724017/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-response-json

Comment: @mohdsarfaraz that's really a totally separate issue to the problem you illustrated in the question. It's unrelated and is a different task you need to complete. Don't be a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/5947043). Instead, if you have a new problem and can't solve it by your own research and coding, then ask a new question.