# Sorting data from API to table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I trying to learn jquery as im new to it. here I have made a request to this example API and got an array of object that i have to list in to the table. However, im stuck on how to sort in to the table? please help me out

I have my html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="ID" id="_id"></td>
      <td data-column="Name" id="_name"></td>
      <td data-column="Age" id="_age"></td>
      <td data-column="Salay" id="_salay"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", function(data, status){
        if(data.status == "success"){
            let listData = JSON.parse(data.data)
            console.log(listData);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

here i got an error as below:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at Function.parse [as parseJSON] ()

Comment: how are you creating table rows are you using any library for table?

Comment: If you break this down in to steps there are lots of questions and tutorials about it already. For example, [this on sorting an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/519413) and [this on creating a table from a JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17724017/519413). What part specifically are you having an issue with?

Comment: @brk no, it's pure html and some css style. no library at all

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you, i will take a look at it

Comment: what is the result of console.log? can you share it?

Comment: @GilangPratama i think the JSON parse is error. the result is error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$.each(listData,function(key,value){

var trrow='<tr><td data-column="ID" id="_id">'+value["ID"]+'</td><td data-column="Name" id="_name">'+value["Name"]+'</td><td data-column="Age" id="_age">'+value["Age"]+'</td><td data-column="Salay" id="_salay">'+value["Salay"]+'</td>
</tr>';

$("tbody").append(trrow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are again parsing a JSON array which is return from API.
Your API is returning the below data.

```
var data={"status":"success","data":[{"id":"1","employee_name":"Tiger Nixon","employee_salary":"320800","employee_age":"61","profile_image":""},{"id":"2","employee_name":"Garrett Winters","employee_salary":"170750","employee_age":"63","profile_image":""},{"id":"3","employee_name":"Ashton Cox","employee_salary":"86000","employee_age":"66","profile_image":""},{"id":"4","employee_name":"Cedric Kelly","employee_salary":"433060","employee_age":"22","profile_image":""},{"id":"5","employee_name":"Airi Satou","employee_salary":"162700","employee_age":"33","profile_image":""},{"id":"6","employee_name":"Brielle Williamson","employee_salary":"372000","employee_age":"61","profile_image":""},{"id":"7","employee_name":"Herrod Chandler","employee_salary":"137500","employee_age":"59","profile_image":""},{"id":"8","employee_name":"Rhona Davidson","employee_salary":"327900","employee_age":"55","profile_image":""},{"id":"9","employee_name":"Colleen Hurst","employee_salary":"205500","employee_age":"39","profile_image":""},{"id":"10","employee_name":"Sonya Frost","employee_salary":"103600","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""},{"id":"11","employee_name":"Jena Gaines","employee_salary":"90560","employee_age":"30","profile_image":""},{"id":"12","employee_name":"Quinn Flynn","employee_salary":"342000","employee_age":"22","profile_image":""},{"id":"13","employee_name":"Charde Marshall","employee_salary":"470600","employee_age":"36","profile_image":""},{"id":"14","employee_name":"Haley Kennedy","employee_salary":"313500","employee_age":"43","profile_image":""},{"id":"15","employee_name":"Tatyana Fitzpatrick","employee_salary":"385750","employee_age":"19","profile_image":""},{"id":"16","employee_name":"Michael Silva","employee_salary":"198500","employee_age":"66","profile_image":""},{"id":"17","employee_name":"Paul Byrd","employee_salary":"725000","employee_age":"64","profile_image":""},{"id":"18","employee_name":"Gloria Little","employee_salary":"237500","employee_age":"59","profile_image":""},{"id":"19","employee_name":"Bradley Greer","employee_salary":"132000","employee_age":"41","profile_image":""},{"id":"20","employee_name":"Dai Rios","employee_salary":"217500","employee_age":"35","profile_image":""},{"id":"21","employee_name":"Jenette Caldwell","employee_salary":"345000","employee_age":"30","profile_image":""},{"id":"22","employee_name":"Yuri Berry","employee_salary":"675000","employee_age":"40","profile_image":""},{"id":"23","employee_name":"Caesar Vance","employee_salary":"106450","employee_age":"21","profile_image":""},{"id":"24","employee_name":"Doris Wilder","employee_salary":"85600","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""}]};

 let listData = JSON.parse(data.data) // replace this line
 let listData=data.data;// its already JSON Array
```

for Example

```
var a=[{name:"John"},{name:"DOE"}]
JSON.parse(a) // it will give you same error which is mentioned in a question.
```